# Cookie Clearing Help Required

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am making an application in which i have used OAuth for loging with Gmail,twitter and yahoo
I am making cookie by using this

```
FormAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username,false)
```

The problem is when i click on logout button it doesn't loggedout from any of these sites(if i logged in) How can i clear cookies on logout this is my logout function

```
Session.Clear();
 FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
 HttpCookie cookie1 = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, "");
  cookie1.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
  Response.Cookies.Add(cookie1);
```

The scenario is working fine if i login with the username and password stored in my database

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try with below code:

```
Session.Clear();
Session.Abandon();
```

Comment: I tried it but still its not signingout from Gmail or any other service